# Induction: confused by $P(k)$ to $P(k+1)$

Tags: induction, divisibility

As far as I know, I know we have to use $P(k)$ to prove $P(k+1)$ in induction instead of going from $P(k+1)$ to $P(k)$.

I want to prove a divisibility problem using the idea of induction, and I can't show the problem here directly but I found a very similar one.

The example I saw online is this: Prove $6^n + 4$ is divisible by $5$ using induction. The URL to this problem is here: https://www.iitutor.com/mathematical-induction-divisibility/

I read his proof steps, I found it very confusing that he actually started the proof from $P(k+1)$, as he proceeded the proof, he confronted the situation where the induction hypotheses can help, then he applies the induction hypothesis to complete the proof.

But wouldn't this be not allowed? Since he actaully started from $P(k+1)$ instead of $P(k)$?

P.S. I have read and confronted several examples that started from $P(k+1)$ instead of $P(k)$, but our professor told us that is actually not logical correct. Which way is truly the correct way to do an induction? I am already lost...

Comment: In the article they show it's true for $0$, then prove it's true for $k+1$ assuming it's true for $k$. That's standard induction. Using your terminology, they are indeed using $P(k)$ to prove $P(k+1)$. You might want to read it carefully again.

Comment: Nope. He assumed P(k) and used to prove P(k+1).

Comment: I'm going through the same issue right now, it shouldn't matter if you start with p(k) or p(k+1) as long as your operations are valid and you demonstrate the equivalence between the equation. My professor is telling me that starting from the p(k+1) is logically invalid but it makes no difference, you just apply the inverse operations if you start with p(k+1), I always get the right answer some how. Did you go to Kutztown by chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to prove that $6^n+4$ is divisible by $5$ for all natural numbers $n$. This proceeds in three steps.

$1.)$ We show that the statement $P(n)$, $6^n+4$ is divisible by $5$, is true for $n=1.$ In other words, we confirm that $P(1)$ is true.

$2.)$ One assumes that the statement $P(n)$ is true for some $k>1$. In other words we assume that $P(k)$ is true, that is, $6^k+4$ is divisible by $5$.

$3.)$ One uses the assumption made in $(2)$ to prove that $P(k+1)$ is true. In other words, we show that $6^{k+1}+4$ is divisible by $5$.

This process proves that $P(n)$ is true $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

**Theorem:**

For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $6^n+4$ is divisible by $5$.

**Proof:**

$1.)$ Clearly $P(1)$ is true since $6^1+4=10$ is divisible by $5$.

$2.)$ Now *assume* that $P(k)$ is true for some $k>1$. That is, assume that $6^k+4$ is divisible by $5$.

$3.)$ Note that $$6^{k+1}+4=6\cdot6^k+4+20-20=6(6^k+4)-20$$ To show that $P(k+1)$ is true, we show that $$\frac{6^{k+1}+4}{5}=\frac{6(6^k+4)}{5}-\frac{20}{5}$$ is an integer. Well, since we assumed that $6^k+4$ is divisible by $5$, clearly $\frac{6(6^k+4)}{5}$ is an integer, as is $\frac{20}{5}=4$.

Therefore we conclude that $P(k+1)$ is true, that is we confirmed that $6^{k+1}+4$ is divisible by $5$.

Comment: Yes, I understand his solution, what I don't understand is that I think he started from P(k+1) instead of P(k), because I think if proving by induction has to start from P(k), then he should get something like 6($6^k$) + 6(4) = 5M, instead of directly 6($6^k$) + 4 = 5M

Comment: What may be happening is he writes down the statement $P(k+1)$ first and then derives (or confirms its truthfulness) from the assumed truthfulness of $P(k)$. So oftentimes one writes down the statement $P(k+1)$ first.

Comment: I have tried the same move before, which is what you said first write down the statement of P(k+1), and derives from there,  and my TA tells me that is not valid, I have to start from P(k) and I can't start from P(k+1). This is essentially the reason I feel so confused because it seems like sometimes people (including my prof) starts from P(k+1), but when you actually do that, they tell you it's not valid.

Comment: So to summarize, is it a YES or NO that I can start by writing down P(k+1) first and derive from there?

Comment: @Metaozis it doesn't matter what you write down first. What matters is that you *always* prove the $k+1$ case assuming the $k$ case is true. If you read the proof carefully, it should be clear that's what's happening.

Comment: Yes I agree with what you said, but isn't the beginning of his step 3 started to derive using P(k+1) instead of P(k)? I mean if he started from P(k), he should have written down something like $6(6^n) + 6(4) = 5(6^n) + 5(4) + 6^n + 4?$, and then apply I.H from there?

Comment: When writing down the expression $P(k+1)$ I'm not assuming anything about its truthfulness or falsity. I am simply trying to manipulate $P(k+1)$ to get it into a form that is *useful*. And by useful, I mean I am trying to put $P(k+1)$ into a form that allows me to use the truth of $P(k)$ to prove the truthfulness of $P(k+1)$. In divisibility induction proofs, this usually amounts to taking advantage of the fact $5|(a+b)$ if $5|a$ and $5|b$ via adding 'something' and subtracting 'something' to utilize $P(k)$.

Answer (score 3):

No, he did not start from $P(k+1)$. He is simply stating what needs to be done in the beginning of Step $3$. That is, he is stating his goal in the first $2$ lines of Step $3$, and then proceeds to achieve that goal.

Comment: Yes I agree with what you said, but isn't the beginning of his step 3 started to derive using P(k+1) instead of P(k)? I mean if he started from P(k), he should have written down something like $6(6^n) + 6(4) = 5(6^n) + 5(4) + 6^n + 4?$, and then apply I.H from there?

Comment: Nope. He is *not* using P(k+1). He needs to compute the expression $6^{k+1}+4$ by using P(k). The expression $6^{k+1}+4$ is *not* the same as P(k+1). Just because $k+1$ appears somewhere, does not mean P(k+1) has been used. To reiterate, P(k+1) is the *statement* $5|6^{k+1}+4$.